# How to hide like,share,comment button from facebook embedded posts?

Tags: facebook

I have embedded a Facebook post on my website, I don't want the default like,share and comment button instead i want a custom button,I can create the custom button, but how to remove the default button provided by Facebook?

Comment: you can only use settings offered by the plugin, but you cannot (and you are not allowed to) hide stuff from social plugins.

Comment: Why would you want that?